# How to convert a curl_init call into curl_multi_init

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to figure out how to change a connection function from a single curl init to use curl multi init.

Here's the existing code:

```
protected function getConnection()
{
    if (!$this->connection) {
        $this->connection = curl_init();
    }

    return $this->connection;
}
```

Here's what I've tried, but it's not doing anything, not even throwing an error:

```
protected function getConnection()
    {
 $mh = curl_multi_init();

 for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++)
 {

  {
        if (!$this->connection) {
            $this->connection[$i] = curl_init();

        }

        return $this->connection[$i];
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $connection[$i]);

 }

  $running = 0;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($running > 0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keep in mind that once a `return` is called, the function stops. Calling a `return` in the middle of your function means that any code following it will not get run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while ($running > 0);
```

This is going to [burn a *lot* of CPU cycles](http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/making-stuff-faster-with-curlmultiexec.html) while not doing very much.

It should eventually complete if the handles are valid, however we can't see how the connection are populated - and it is not clear why you initalize an array value then return from the method if the connection variable is false. Is the code getting stuck in the loop or just returning in the earlier if statement? If the former is the case then add a timeout as per the linked example. If the latter then populate the connection array before calling the method.

Comment: Connections come in from a function call in a different part of the code. Thanks for the hints - I'll adapt to populate the handle at call time.